# does valueType.ToString() does a cast on the valueType?

Tags: c#, value-type, boxing, unboxing

lets say, i have the following code in c#

```
int x = 0;
x.ToString();
```

does this internally does a boxing of x? 
Is there a way to see this happening from visual studio?

Comment: No it doesn't. The `ToString` implementation on `int` will return the string representation of the `int`, which is more a conversion. No casting or boxing is in sight in this instance. As Daniel asks, why do you want to know this? Is there an underlying issue?

Comment: what do you mean by string representation of int?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - correct but ToString() is defined in System.Object so it is a fair question.

Comment: and since the original question is for ValueTypes, what about struct ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I never said it wasn't fair, I was just trying to make sure there wasn't a larger issue underneath, or an XY problem question.

Comment: A more interesting question could be probably made for `GetType()`, because it isn't overridden in value types and is defined only in `System.Object`.

Comment: @TijuJohn `struct` is a value type... unless I'm missing your point?

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, calling `GetType` on an `int` boxes the int. But why would you call `GetType` on an unboxed `int`? **You already know what type it is.**  Just say `typeof(int)` if you need that type object. (If you are calling it on a boxed `int` then obviously there is no boxing penalty because it's already boxed by assumption.)

Comment: @EricLippert I was thinking more in terms of `T : struct`, but even then it's useless, and `GetType()` is the only relevant non-virtual method of `System.Object`, because the others are protected or virtual or special or static.

Comment: @xanatos: Your analysis is correct. You can say `typeof(T)` in the generic case and you'll get the type object for the type *argument*, not the type *parameter*. Moreover, it is *dangerous* to say `t.GetType()` for `t` of type `T` (this time assuming no constraint) because `T` could be `int?` and `t` could be `null`, in which case you box `t` to `null` reference and then dereference it to call `GetType()`, crashing.

Comment: @xanatos: Moreover: if `T` is `int?` and `t` is not `null` then you box `t` to `int` and `GetType()` returns the `int` type, not the `int?` type, which is probably unexpected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this specific case, you are using a `System.Int32` (an `int`). That type redefines `ToString`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so no boxing.

If you use a `struct` that doesn't redefine `ToString` what you'll have is a `constrained callvirt` to `System.Object.ToString()`. The definition of [constrained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx):

> When a callvirt  method instruction has been prefixed by constrained  thisType, the instruction is executed as follows:
>
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType implements method then ptr is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a call method instruction, for the implementation of method by thisType.
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method then ptr is dereferenced, **boxed**, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt  method instruction.

So there isn't boxing if the value type implements `ToString` and there is boxing if it doesn't implement it... Interesting. I didn't know.

For non-virtual methods like `GetType()` that are defined in `System.Object` the value type is always boxed. Just tested with a:

```
5.GetType();
```

resulting IL code:

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the IL generated by your code:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  ldloca.s    00 // x
IL_0005:  call        System.Int32.ToString
```

As you can see no boxing is taking place.

On the other hand, this code

```
object x = 0;
x.ToString();
```

will not surprisingly cause boxing:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  box         System.Int32
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0009:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
```

Generally, if if the type of `x` is not `int` but any value type (`struct`) then you have to override `ToString` to avoid boxing. Specifically, a [*constrained*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) `callvirt` is emited:

> - If thisType is a value type and thisType implements method then ptr is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a call  method instruction, for the implementation of method by thisType.
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt  method instruction.

If you want to avoid boxing when calling `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString` on a value type you need to override these methods.

Comment: what will happen if x is a struct?